# why spark sql get so slow at last serval task, even a plain table scan?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

env: jdk1.8 with spark 2.3.0 & hadoop 2.8.0

query:

```
select cast(uid as int) from HiveTable where partition=foo
```

physical plan of such a query should be like project <---- filter <---- HiveTableScan(predicate = foo) , a pretty simple one

and the dataframe call:

```
df.write.option("delimiter","\t").csv(HdfsPath)
```

the partition folder contains a lot of lzo files, file size is basically the same so what I expect is every task takes some time and it proceed steady and smoothly.

But it gets slower and slower when reaching the end, looks pretty much like classic `Data Skew` is happening. I really don't know what's happening and how to investigate deeper.

Any advise is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what your data in the partition looks like

Comment: Is table bucketed?

Comment: @salmanbw u mean distribution?

Comment: @user9613318 no, it's not

Answer (score 0):

How did I solve the problem:

use less executor then it runs fine.

conf cause problem:  `--num-executors 512` (cluster have far more than enough resources)

change to 128 solved the problem.

still don't know why, and explanation is welcome.